# Adobe Fireworks - Customising States

Tags: adobe-fireworks

when creating multiple states and making changes it updates both states - when I only want the changes to appear on the state I'm working on at the time. How can I ensure that the changes don't duplicate across all states, & only update the state I'm working on?
I've tried all the obvious selections/buttons... i.e. add new states as opposed to duplicate state.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're working on a layer that's set to be [shared across states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00db4b-7f72.html#WSc1b83f70210cd101-61fc117e125b9e609bc-8000)?